# Regarding MCD43 products

Tags: modis

I have a special MCD43 daily product with 250 m resolution in .hdf format. Whenever I try to open it in the MODIS Re projection Tool, the error i get is "error in module:read hdr file". What should I do? I want to convert these files to .tiff format. Please help!

Comment: Can you offer a link to a file to try?